# How to detect user input language in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect user input(numbers pad) language is English or Persian.
I'm using the following scripts but they work when user OS is Linux, but not when users OS is windows.
first solution:

```
      document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
      var patt = new RegExp("^[\u06F0-\u06F9]+$");
      if (patt.test(e.key)) 
        document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = "Persian";                            
      else 
        document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML = "english";
         })
```

Second solution:

```
  document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
  if (isPersian(e.charCode))
  document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML='Persian';
  else
  document.getElementById("lang").innerHTML='English';

     });

  function isPersian(charCode){
    return (charCode >= 1776 && charCode <= 1785) 
  }
```

Comment: `window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language`, you wont get `English` though your have to key it in from `en-GB`

Comment: window.navigator.language returns only en-US for both English keyboard and Persian Keyboard @Lawrence Cherone

Comment: Have you set your language to `English (United Kingdom)`, or is it set to the more-or-less default `English (United States)`? My own browser - Firefox - returns `en-GB` in response to `console.log(window.navigator.language)` but other than the fact I explicitly selected UK language I don't know why yours would be different. Regardless, though, you can still extrapolate English from the `en` portion.

Comment: navigator.language property returns the browser language not the user's keyboard language. @David Thomas .